# Angular-cli, RC5 material2: Unexpected Token import

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

I am trying to configure Material 2 with Angular-cli RC5. When I am trying to load material button component in app.module.ts I am getting following error.

```
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:4203/app/app.module.js:22:16)
        at eval (http://localhost:4203/app/app.module.js:47:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:4203/app/app.module.js:48:3)
    Evaluating http://localhost:4203/vendor/@angular2-material/button/button.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4203/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:4203/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:4203/main.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import(…)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.7-4",
    "@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.7-4",,
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12",
    "d3": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^0.3.0",
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "1.3.1"
  }
}
```

angular-cli-build.js

```
/* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular2-material/**/*',
    ]
  });
};
```

system.config.ts

```
"use strict";

/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  '@angular2-material': 'vendor/@angular2-material',
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const materialPackages:string[] = [
  'core',
  'button'
];
const packages:any = {};
materialPackages.forEach(name => {
  packages[`@angular2-material/${name}`] = {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: name
  };
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
 **********************************************************************************************/
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app'
  /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
  cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'main': 'main.js'
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule}           from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule}      from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent}       from './app.component';
import {HttpModule}         from '@angular/http';
import {FormsModule}        from '@angular/forms';
import {RouterModule}       from '@angular/router';
import {MdButtonModule}     from '@angular2-material/button';
import {MdCoreModule}       from '@angular2-material/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports     : [BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    MdButtonModule
    MdCoreModule],
  bootstrap   : [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app.module.ts has an instruction for ripple module from core that prevents a bug of adding gaps to the page on button click

```
import { MdRippleModule } from '@angular2-material/core';
import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';
```

To use that module, you'll need to add the following to your package.json

```
"@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.7-4",
```

Just as you did for material2 button, you'll also need to install that core module in your project.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/core

Also, I would suggest to look into switching for angular-cli webpack before your prototype gets too big. Doing so will declutter the settings you are using, give better performance when bundling and you'll be jumping in the webpack hypetrain, which is a good investment because angular-cli is moving from systemjs to webpack.

Comment: I tryed by adding material core component but the issue is still there :(

Comment: While not an immediate solution to your problem, I reiterate my invitation to switch to webpack. I am sure it will be a good move in the long run and will likely fix this problem. Switching from systemjs to webpack took me at least a full day. Edit: People in the material2 chat might be able to solve your problem quickly : https://gitter.im/angular/material2

Comment: Thanks Dave fro your instructions. I migrated my app to webpack. now the things are working fine. Many thanks to you.

Comment: @Rose18 Glad it worked for the best. I had the same struggle. It might be a good to idea to mark this answer as accepted to  inform others that your issue is resolved.